# Php rand vs Perl rand

Tags: php, perl, random

I am trying to port a piece of code from perl to php. The perl code snippet is part of akamai's video on demand link generation script. The script generates seed based on the location / URL of the video file (which will always be constant for a single URL). And then it is used in generating serial ID for stream (which is basically a random number between 1 and 2000 using the seed). Here is the perl code.

```
$seed=6718;
srand($seed);
print(int(rand(1999)) + 1); // return 442 every time
```

And the converted PHP code is:

```
$seed=6718;
srand($seed);
echo(rand(0, 1999) + 1); //returns 155 every time
```

Does php rand behaves differently than perl one?

Comment: Sorry, I have to: http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: Relying on a consistent set of numbers coming back from `rand` points to deeper issues in the code.  I'm hoping this is just a curiosity and not some porting issue.  If the latter, do a one-time dump of the "random" numbers from perl and PHP, do whatever mapping you need to do, then remove the dependency on  non-random randoms.

Comment: @Mark: Depends on what the code is doing. Many games, for instance, provide random map generation and will also tell you the seed used by any particular map so you can use that seed to replay the same map (or send it to friends, etc.) in the future without having to provide for a "save map" capability. That's a perfectly valid use case for depending on repeatable sequences of (pseudo-)random numbers. Without knowing what the OP's code does, we can't judge whether such a dependency is appropriate or not.

Comment: @Dave - Excellent point.  Well, let's hope it fits your use case and not what I was imagining.

Comment: @Dave: Yes that is correct. I have modified the question accordingly.

Comment: @Dave Sherohman, For a use like that in a game you don't want to use the `rand()` built in of most languages. They are very system dependent and subject to change unless documented otherwise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  You can't depend on their algorithms being the same.  For perl, which rand is used depends on what platform your perl was built for.

You may have more luck using a particular algorithm; for instance, Mersenne Twister looks to be available for both [PHP](http://www.phpdig.net/ref/rn35re672.html) and [Perl](http://p3rl.org/Math%3a%3aRandom%3a%3aMT).
Update: trying it produces different results, so that one at least won't do the trick.

Update 2: From the perl numbers you show, your perl is using the drand48 library; I don't know whether that's available for PHP at all, and google isn't helping.

Answer (score 2):

[clippy]It looks like your trying to hash a number, maybe you want to use a hash function?[/clippy]

Hash functions are designed to take an input and produce a consistently repeatable value, that is in appearance random. As a bonus they often have cross language implementations.

Using `srand()` with `rand()` to get what is basically a hash value is a fairly bad idea. Different languages use different algorithms, some just use system libraries. Changing (or upgrading) the OS, standard C library, or language can result in wildly different results.

Using SHA1 to get a number between 1 and 2000 is a bit overkill, but you can at least be sure that you could port the code to nearly any language and still get the same result.

```
use Digest::SHA1;

# get a integer hash value from $in between $min (inclusive) and $max (exclusive)
sub get_int_hash {
    my ($in, $min, $max) = @_;

    # calculate the SHA1 of $in, note $in is converted to a string.
    my $sha  = Digest::SHA1->new;
    $sha->add( "$in" );
    my $digest = $sha->hexdigest;
    # use the last 7 characters of the digest (28 bits) for an effective range of 0 - 268,435,455.
    my $value = hex substr $digest, -7;
    # scale and shift the value to the desired range.
    my $out = int( $value / 0x10000000 * ( $max - $min ) ) + $min;

    return $out;
}
print get_int_hash(6718, 1, 2000); #this should print 812 for any SHA1 implementation.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just seeing this snippet of code it is impossible to say if it is the same.

At first you need to knew that even a random generator like the `rand()` function is not really random. It calculates a new value with a mathematical formula from the previous number. With the `srand()` function you can set the start value.

Calling `srand()` with the same argument each time means that the program always returns the same numbers in the same order.

If you really want random numbers, in Perl you should remove the initialization of `srand()`. Because Perl automatically sets `srand()` to a better (random) value when you first call the `rand()` function.

If your program really wants random numbers, then it should also be okay for PHP. But even in PHP i would look if `srand()` is automatically set and set to a more random value.

If your program don't work with random numbers and instead really want a stream of numbers that is always the same, then the snipet of code are probably not identical. Even if you do the same initialization with srand() it could be that PHP uses another formula to calculate the next "random" number.

So you need to look at your surrounding code if you code really wants random numbers, if yes you can use this code. But even then you should look for a better initialization for srand().

Comment: If you really want random numbers, you wouldn't use rand() at all.

Comment: Sure, rand() is not random enough for cryptography, but for a lot of cases it is just enough. And i think i have answered the question if it is the same good enough. And i don't think a downvote is correct. Even if you mention that rand() is not random enough.

Comment: @Sid One seed is not better than another in terms of providing more randomness in some sense. These are *pseudo-random* numbers, regardless of the quality of the generator. So, if you really want *random* numbers, you'd use something else which is the point brian is trying to make.

Comment: Perl automatically pick a random seed, not a static one. So not setting srand() lets to "better" random numbers. That doesn't mean that they are not pseudo generated. And the whole point of the question was if the PHP Code and Perl Code is the same. Not how good the pseudo-random number generator is.

Comment: I said, that it depends on what the application do with the numbers. If the application uses that numbers as random numbers, then the code is equal. If the application uses the numbers as a stream that should always return the same numbers then the code is not equal.  The `real` is how his application thread the numbers. Not if `rand()` returns real random numbers. The whole discussion if `rand()` returns real random numbers is just a waist of time and was not the question and was not what i said. I already said it in the second sentence that `rand()` does not return real random numbers.